# is there anyway to access a css class in another html file which belongs to another component in Angularjs?

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs

I have two components like this:

/top-navbar

top-navbar.component.js

top-navbar.module.js

top-navbar.template.html

and the other one is

/main-list

main-list.component.js

main-list.module.js

main-list.template.html

I have a function in:

top-navbar.component.js

which should take a css class in

main-list.template.html

and change it's value to what I need.

how should I do it?

I would appreciate it if you could help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following

```
const myElement = document.getElementsByClassName('my-element')[0];
```

`document.getElementsByClassName` will return `HTMLCollenction`, so with `[0]` you take a first element of it.

Then if you need to manipulate a class name

```
myElement.classList.add('MyClass');

myElement.classList.remove('MyClass');

if ( myElementclassList.contains('MyClass') )

myElement.classList.toggle('MyClass');
```